# Show the the following vectors are linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Show that the following vectors are linearly independence on $a\leq t \leq b$

$$\phi_1(t)=\left(\begin{array}{c}t\\ 0\end{array}\right)$$

$$\phi_2(t)=\left(\begin{array}{c}t^2\\ 0\end{array}\right)$$

My work:

I try to find the determinant of the vectors and they are zeroes,

$$\left\|\begin{matrix}t & t^2 \\0 & 0 \end{matrix}\right\|=(t)(0)-t^2(0)$$

$$\left\|\begin{matrix}t & t^2 \\0 & 0 \end{matrix}\right\|=0$$

$$c_1\phi_1(t)+c_2\phi_2(t)=0$$

$$c_1t+c_2t^2=0$$

$$c_1+c_2t=0$$

$$c_1=0,c_2=0$$

Is this the right way to show it?

Comment: You'll have to tell us what vector space these are in.

Comment: Presumably, it is the vector space of functions $[a,b]\to\mathbb R^2$, or some subspace thereof.

Comment: I am not sure about it because the zeroes of the second dimension make it looks more like  a one dimension vector.